# Why does the MySQL SLEEP() function return 0?

Tags: mysql, function, unix, return-value

When I run a sleep command in MySQL, e.g. `SELECT SLEEP(7)`, it returns zero. Why is this? Is it following the standard Unix convention of return values? Does it just need something to return and so zero is a good harmless value? Are there other MySQL functions that behave like this?

Comment: If it makes it through the sleep period, it returns 0. If the sleep is interrupted for some reason, it returns 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_sleep):

> SLEEP(duration)
>
> Sleeps (pauses) for the number of seconds given by the duration
>   argument, then returns 0. If SLEEP() is interrupted, it returns 1. The
>   duration may have a fractional part given in microseconds. This
>   function was added in MySQL 5.0.12.

Comment: Odd. I found that when I interupted it with the keyboard it didn't return anything at all (it drew the little table, which had a header, but the other part was just empty).

Comment: Probably because that interrupts the mysql client, and stops it from receiving any response from the server.

Comment: @Kazark: You're probably not familiar with query killers, see e.g. the [pt-kill program](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-kill.html) by Percona. If the server kills the sleep() query it will return 1 on the client. This is a great way to test query killers that work based on a maximum execution time for queries.